# Could anyone identify this crDroid ROM?

Tags: security, custom-roms

Found some third-party [crDROID 7.11 build](https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=7161016148664826190)  that works flawlessly on my phone, g530FZ. However, I couldn't find it listed on any credible sources (such as XDA). Anyone else used this rom or saw any info on it? Details below:

- I've been looking for a LineageOS 17.1 build for my phone, G530FZ
  Galaxy Grand Prime (or "gprimeltexx") to switch to from LineageOS 18
  due to slowdowns and short battery life on newer version.
- Decided to search androidfilehost.com to look for "gprimeltexx".
- Unexpectedly, the crDroid 7.11 (Android 11) 2021 build for g530FZ (highlighted) showed up in the search. crDroid does not officially support g530FZ

  - Previously I've searched high and low for crDroid build for g530FZ that is newer than 2018 (xda thread) to no avail.
  - Scouring the google and duckduckgo for variations of "crDroid 7.11 grand prime" yielded no results EXCEPT this androidfilehost file. Searching for the highlighted rom filename shows ONLY this androidfilehost link in the results.
  - Since my phone was long wiped anyway, I've decided to download and flash this crDroid rom via TWRP.
  - Surprisingly, it did flash, and after about 5 min of initialization I was prompted to go through regular Android initial setup (language, etc)
  - Even more surprises: despite running Android 11 (which has always been slow on the prehistoric Grand Prime), this crDroid rom runs very fast even with all the fancy animations (which mercilessly lagged the device on lineageos 18)

I am tempted to use this rom as my main phone os. HOWEVER, given that it came from a totally random source and has no info on it on XDA, I am naturally hesitant. Could anyone could clarify the following please:

Does this ROM come from XDA or some other credible sources? I've searched on it myself couldnt find anything, but maybe I've missed something that you know. Developer of the ROM is listed as "AaronPhilips101". Does that ring a bell?

Comment: install telegram and contact dev

Comment: Please note that ROM development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users or power-users (but not necessarily developers) solving their issues, so we can't really provide any tutorials about building a ROM.

Comment: @AndrewT. Ok, thanks for the tip. Removed the dev part of the question

Comment: You can find other files for the same phone from the same developper posted on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/aaronphilips101/files/GrandPrime/). The developer as posted his telegram [link]( http://t.me/AaronPhilips101). I think you should follow @alecxs advice and contact him directly.